# How do I get the Account Object to update when an Account Memeber is added?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have attempted to update the Account when a Team member is added to the Account

```
public Class checkRecursive
{ 
  private static boolean run = true; 
  public static boolean runOnce()
  { 
    return run;
  }
}

trigger UpdateBankRep on Account (Before update, Before insert)
{
  if(checkRecursive.runOnce()) 
  { 

    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Account acct : Trigger.new)
    {
      accountIds.add(acct.Id);
    }

    list<AccountTeamMember> accounts = [Select Id,User.Name from AccountTeamMember where TeamMemberRole = 'Banking Rep' And AccountId IN :accountIds Limit 1];

    if(accounts.size() > 0)
    {
      for(Account acctTeam : Trigger.New )
      {
        acctTeam.Banking_Rep__c = accounts[0].User.Name;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      for(Account acctTeam : Trigger.New )
      {
        acctTeam.Banking_Rep__c = '';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one Banking_Rep__c per account, might I suggest you switch things around the other way. You could write a trigger on the account that on insert, update if there was a Banking_Rep__c added, it would create the Account Team member record automatically.

```
trigger UpdateBankRepTeam on Account (After update, After insert){
    UpdateBRHelper.updateTeamMember(trigger.new)
}
```

Then have this helper class:

```
 public class UpdateBRHelper{
    public static void updateTeamMember(List<Account> accounts){
        List<AccountTeamMember> ATM = new List<AccountTeamMember>();
        for(Account a:accounts){
           if(a.Banking_Rep__c != null){
              AccountTeamMember Teammemberad=new AccountTeamMember();
              Teammemberad.AccountId=a.id;
              Teammemberad.UserId=a.Banking_Rep__c;
              Teammemberad.TeamMemberRole = 'Banking Rep';
              ATM.add(Teammemberad);
        }
        if(!ATM.isEmpty()){
           insert ATM;
        }
    }          

 }
```

If the Banking rep is switching alot, you could also add code to delete the existing team member, then add the new one.

If you want to add sharing for the record at the same time,you would need to add something like this:

```
//before the for loop
List<AccountShare> ashareLIST = new List<AccountShare>();

//inside the for loop
AccountShare caSharingRule = new AccountShare();
   caSharingRule.AccountId = a.Id;
   caSharingRule.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Read';
   caSharingRule.CaseAccessLevel = 'Read';
   caSharingRule.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
   caSharingRule.UserOrGroupId = a.Banking_Rep__c;
   ashareLIST.add(caSharingRule);

 //after the insert of the team member
 insert ashareLIST;
```

Comment: JimRae, that is a good idea.  How would I be able to add the record access into that?

Comment: @Liz, that is where things get a bit convoluted. The access is actually controlled by sharing rules.  What you would need to do is add an AccountSharing rule for the user being added at the same time.  I will update my response above.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you and let you know it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Currently you can't build any trigger or workflow on AccountTeamMember....
Your only choice is to create trigger on Account and check on update or (better but it is IMHO little too much) build  scheduled batch job to do it everyday.

I will write some simple trigger (I am not big fan of putting logic inside of trigger so I will call some method):

Trigger

```
trigger UpdateBankRep on Account (After update, After insert){
    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)){
          SomeClass.someMethod(trigger.new)
    }
}
```

Class

```
    public class SomeClass{
        public static void someMethod(List<Account> accounts){
            List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
            for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM AccountTeamMembers) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : accounts){
    /**  Number_Of_Account_Members__c - custom field to keep number of related objects **/
                if(acc.Number_Of_Account_Members__c != acc.AccountTeamMembers.size()){
                    /** Here put update actions **/
                    accountsToUpdate.add(acc); 
                }
            }
            update accountsToUpdate;
        }
   }
```

How about that?